# Does continuous joint density implies continuous marginal density?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ be the joint pdf of a random vector $(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$, which is assumed to be continuous. Now, consider the marginal density $\hat f(x_1, \cdots, x_{n-1}) = \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_{n-1}} f(y)dy_{n-1} \cdots dy_1$. Can I conclude that $\hat f$ is also a continuous function?

I think there must be a counterexample, since I cannot prove this.

Answer (score -1):

It follows from the fact, that if function's derivative is continious, so is the function

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit, please, and specify which functions you are talking about., please?  The joint density function is not the derivative of the marginal density, nor the other way around, so your answer puzzled me.